# How would one add a lens flare effect to clean footage? (Picture attached)

Tags: video, premiere, adobe, effects

I have some footage of traffic, varying in range from close-up to distant and would like to add what I think is a lens flare effect to make it look like the picture attached.

The online tutorials I have found only talk about adding a lens flare generator (useful for the kind of flare you would get from the sun) which acts as an overlay rather than actually affecting the footage.

If anyone has any tips, pointers or recommendations they would be greatly appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call that a lens flare, I'd call it a star filter. I know Red Giant do one (commercial) called Star Glow: https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-starglow/

Comment: @stib yes! Thank you so much. Been trying Star Glow and getting a decent effect. Just need to figure out the best configurations to get it looking nice. Might be difficult getting it like the picture but it’s looking alright atm.

Comment: You could also use two blur effects, one vertical and one horizontal.

Comment: @stib trying to imagine how that would work. Would you set it to blur only the highlights? Is that possible with a stock premiere blur? I’ll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: ah, Premiere, didn't read the question well enough. It's probably possible, but easier in AE. Yes, you'd use curves to grab just the highlights and blur them. But you'd need to make copies of the layer and nest them probably.